# Xcode broke YouCompleteMe error highlighting

Tags: c++, xcode, vim, g++, clang

I was working a project in `C++` and all of the sudden my Mac said that Xcode was finished updating, so I just exited out of the popup and didn't think anything of it.  I went back to my project and tried to run my makefile and it said I need to be root to accept Xcode's terms.  So, I just booted up Xcode, accepted the terms, and quit.  Now, when I work on my project in Vim, I am getting all kinds of errors.  E.g.

```
#include<iostream>  // 'iostream' file not found
#include<string>

int main()
{   
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; // use of undeclared identifier 'std'
    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea what has happened.  Can anybody help me?

I use `g++` to compile and this is the output of `g++ --version`:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-    include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

My `Xcode` version is now `6.0.1`.

All this being said, I still seem to be able to compile my code.  I am just getting all types of errors in Vim, related somehow to this Xcode update.

I use `YouCompleteMe` for error highlighting.

Comment: Tom Cruise is obviously displeased with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I have found the solution.  I am assuming that when Xcode updated, its folder structure changed.

I fixed this issue by changing my `.ycm_extra_conf.py`.  I changed the flag line

```
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1'
```

to

```
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1',
```